# error nginx dependency on centos 6

Tags: nginx, centos, centos6

i've just setup my server using centos 6.4, and right now i want to install nginx using yum, but i always get error require dependency. but i check on /usr/lib64/ library is not missing.
i really don't understand how to solve this.

this is my nginx.repo

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

this is error from yum install nginx

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 0:1.4.6-1.el6.ngx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: nginx-1.4.6-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: nginx-1.4.6-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit) for package: nginx-1.4.6-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nginx-1.4.6-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: nginx-1.4.6-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
Error: Package: nginx-1.4.6-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/581392/centos-6-3-openssl-1-0-1

Comment: i see, thanks, but i think i cannot upgrade to centos 6.5, because i use centos version from hosting provider on my vps.

Comment: You don't need to upgrade centos. All you need is to install openssl 1.0.1, that is available now for all 6.x versions.

Comment: hmm... i just try to search on google but they said it's not safe because many component on centos 6.4 still using openssl 1.0, i don't know it's true or not.